# How to map wan to my voip lan?

Tags: firewall, nat, sonicwall

I am using SonicWall NSA 2400 in my organization. We configured two different lans in  x0 and x3 interfaces. Initially we have only one Internet line which we configured in x2 and both the lan interfaces uses the internet line. Now we have a backup line from another provider.

I have to do NAT as below:

LAN x0 -> x2 TaTa

LAN x3 -> x4 AirTel

Now I am confusing how to NAT voip lan(x3) to new interface (x4).

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

login to Sonicwall and go to Network --> Routes.    Add following routes [image]